# Making sense out of PyArrow

Tags: python, design-patterns, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am browsing the tutorials and the documentation of `PyArrow`. I see some redundancies, for example, when reading a **parquet** Dataset (or folder) I could either

```
type1 = pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset("Pqfolder/", use_legacy_dataset=False)
# or
type2 = pyarrow.dataset.dataset('Pqfolder/', format='parquet')
```

What are `pyarrow.parquet` and `pyarrow.dataset`? Are they modules of the `pyarrow` package? Where do I find the docs? It looks like `pyarrow.dataset` is explained in https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/dataset.html and `pyarrow.parquet` in https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html So i wonder why it is not `pyarrow.api.dataset`...

From what I understood the API (`pyarrow.dataset`) also allows you to filter the data with the `scanner` method, while with `pyarrow.parquet` I can only do the filtering when I read the file/s with `filters` but after that I can only `read` without filtering. Also, filtering is richer thanks to expressions... So, what's the point of having `pyarrow.parquet` if it can only do a subset of what `pyarrow.dataset` does (using a different notation)?

The issue here is that I have understood all this by guessing, trials and errors. Is this the standard way in which one learns about new libraries or did I miss some docs?
I think I am missing some basics in software design. I was wondering if anyone could point me to some reference about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where `pyarrow.api.dataset` would come from; the docs path is just to delineate the API reference documentation vs the higher-level user documentation. So you actually want https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html.

The Arrow project is working on improving documentation. `pyarrow.parquet` precedes `pyarrow.dataset` by quite a bit, and is being reworked to delegate to `pyarrow.dataset` internally. (You could think of `pyarrow.dataset` as generalizing `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset` to non-Parquet files, and potentially to things that aren't files at all.) `pyarrow.parquet` also has the 'lower level' functions to just read a Parquet file, much like `pyarrow.csv` does for CSV.